# FreeBSD top disk io read write units

Tags: freebsd, top

In FreeBSD you can run "top -m io" and it will show you disk io.

For example:

[image]

What units is the WRITE/READ in, bytes or kilobytes or megabytes?

Comment: if I had to guess, it's probably lowest one possible (aka bytes)

Comment: @alexus well that would be logical however I'm seeing values like 1 and 15 and I doubt that is correct since it doesn't line up with using iostat, it might even represent some other unit completely other than byte.

Comment: Did you look at `man top`? Also, FreeBSD is not Linux. Removed tag.

Comment: @Rob dropping some knowledge, ty, I did look at the man page but it was not obvious unless you are indirectly telling me I missed something

Answer (score 0):

The `top` manual page refers to the [`getrusage(2)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getrusage&sektion=2&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.0-RELEASE+and+Ports) system call which generates the following block device statistics:

> **`ru_inblock`**      the number of times the file system had to perform input.
>
> **`ru_oublock`**    the number of times the file system had to perform output.

and those numbers have no unit, they seem to be event counters.

Comment: The unit is right in the name: _block_

Comment: Based on other context in the man page, I'm thinking that `block` refers to "block device" rather than "blocks of data".  So the unit of the counter is most likely "event".  Although, a block device isn't a filesystem, so I'm not inclined to trust the authors of that documentation particularly far.